# Cocoa: App uses more CPU when in the background?

Tags: cocoa, background, cpu, popover

I'm making a mac app that appears as a popover from the menu bar. The view has several components, when everything is running and the popover is open I see that it is taking up about 3% CPU. However when I minimize the popover and let it run it the background it jumps up to 6-7% CPU. This does not make any sense to me since the view is no longer being shown so I would imagine less would be required to run.

However I am not doing anything when I close the popover, just sending a [popover close] message.

Is there something else I should be doing when I close the popover to keep down CPU usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your code, it is hard to say what's going on. You will need to find that out by using [Instruments Time Profiler](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html). Once you know what the application is doing while minimized, you should be able to locate and fix the issue.